# Equals sign in the pdftitle using hyperref

Tags: symbols, hyperref

I have a paper with an equation in the title, and I would like to include the equals sign in the pdf metadata by using the hyperref key "pdftitle", by including it as in the following:

```
\hypersetup{pdftitle={P = NP}}
```

But when I typeset this, the metadata stops just after the P.

So my question is, *how can I get the symbol = to appear in the pdf metadata with hyperref?*
I'm using TeX+DVI, in case that matters.

---

After Ulrike kindly pointed out the there was no problem.  I tried to just restart to see if the problem evaproated... and it did!  I'll leave this up in case someone else has something similar happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me. The Reader shows the title P = NP with both compile routes (pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={P = NP}}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

I'm using hyperref.sty    2010/06/18 v6.81g Hypertext links for LaTeX